# Difference in results between C# and C++ implementation (generate unique permutations)

Tags: c#, c++

I feel super silly , but I can't figure this out.

I am trying to solve one of the questions from Leetcode - https://leetcode.com/problems/permutations-ii/. I came across one solution in C++ that didn't know how it works, so I decided to try it with debugger. 
I implemented it in C#, but I get different result. I can't figure out why, to me the code is the same.

Here is the C++ code:

```
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <algorithm>    // std::sort
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

void sw(vector<int> &num, int i, int j) {
    int tmp = num[i];
    num[i] = num[j];
    num[j] = tmp;
}

void recursion(vector<int> num, int i, int j, vector<vector<int> > &res)
{   
    if (i == j - 1) {
        res.push_back(num);
        return;
    }
    for (int k = i; k < j; k++) {
        if (i != k && num[i] == num[k]) continue;
        sw(num, i, k);
        recursion(num, i + 1, j, res);
    }
}

vector<vector<int> > permuteUnique(vector<int> &num) {
    sort(num.begin(), num.end());
    vector<vector<int> >res;
    recursion(num, 0, num.size(), res);
    return res;
}



int main()
{
    int myints[] = { 1, 1, 2 };
    std::vector<int> fifth(myints, myints + sizeof(myints) / sizeof(int));
    auto r = permuteUnique(fifth);
    cout << "Count: " << r.size() << "; " ;


    return 0;
}
```

Result of the run is: `[1, 1, 2]`, `[1, 2, 1]`, `[2, 1, 1]`
Here is the C# Code:

```
public class T47_Permutations_Unique
    {
        public static IList<IList<int>> PermuteUnique(int[] nums)
        {
            if (nums == null || nums.Length == 0)
            {
                return null;
            }

            IList<IList<int>> result = new List<IList<int>>();
            Array.Sort(nums);
            ComputeInternal(nums, result, 0, nums.Length);

            return result;
        }

        private static void ComputeInternal(int[] num, IList<IList<int>> result, int i, int j)
        {
            if (i == j-1)
            {
                var row = new List<int>();
                for (int z = 0; z < num.Length; z++)
                {
                    row.Add(num[z]);
                }
                result.Add(row);
                return;
            }
            for (int k = i; k < j; k++)
            {
                if (i != k && num[i] == num[k])
                {
                    continue;
                }
                Swap(num, i, k);
                ComputeInternal(num, result, i + 1, j);
            }
        }

        private static void Swap(int[] input, int i, int j)
        {
            var tmp = input[i];
            input[i] = input[j];
            input[j] = tmp;
        }
    }

[Fact]
        public void SmokeTest()
        {
            var input = new int[] {1, 1, 2};
            var result = T47_Permutations_Unique.PermuteUnique(input);
            Assert.Equal(3, result.Count);
        }
```

And the result is (5 elements instead of 3): `[1, 1, 2]`, `[1, 2, 1]`, `[2, 1, 1]`, `[1, 1, 2]`, `[1, 2, 1]`

Both apps are essentially the same, why is there a difference in results?

Comment: Instead of asking broad question "hey, look at those 2 different sources and tell me where is my mistake" you can ask more appropriate "hey, here is C# source, i expect this result, but it produce that, where is my mistake".

Comment: well, that is not my question. My question is: I have the algo implemented in C++ and C#. They should produce the same results. But the results are different. It is not even important which result is correct. Even if they are both incorrect, but I expect them to be at least the same.